# Onepage checkout error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout, javascript

Does anyone know what is causing this error in Onepage Checkout?

I can't progress to the billing step when I click continue:

> 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null '

Shows in the error console.

I am using the default theme on the frontend but have a custom template for another store which doesn't have this issue.

I've searched and searched but cannot find a solution other than reinstall...

Can someone assist me please?
[Link](http://uk-dev3.thanedirect.com)

Comment: You will need to post a link to your dev site to fix this particular js error on a custom theme.

Comment: That URL did not load for me...

Comment: @Theodores see edit

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809983/typeerror-element-is-null-break-on-this-error-element-style-display-none vote to close!

Comment: @Theodores Agreed, I think that also may be the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing some DOM elements and/or ids. For example in your checkout there is not element with ID: 'billing-buttons-container' or 'shipping-buttons-container'. I think these are the elements that are null when trying to set some properties on them.
You might be missing other elements also. I recommend to compare your checkout templates with the default templates.